# Why does The Sorting Hat sing?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

In Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone (the first book), the Sorting Hat starts to sing, describing the different houses.

Why does it do so?

Comment: Because teenagers (and tweenagers) have short attention spans?

Comment: Why does *anyone* sing?

Comment: @phantom42 - Revenge.

Comment: Revenge? Singing and revenge?

Comment: @user43664 - You know the old saying; 'Singing is a dish best served fabulous'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to Ron it's a tradition. He ascribed the motivation as probably being boredom.

> *The Great Hall rang with applause as the Sorting Hat finished.
>
>   ‘That’s not the song it sang when it sorted us,’ said Harry, clapping along with everyone else.*
>   ***‘Sings a different one every year,’ said Ron. ‘It’s got to be a pretty boring life, hasn’t it, being a hat? I suppose it spends all year making up the next one.’***  <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

Comment: completely canon.. great observation...